# Outlook Anywhere connectivity

Tags: email, outlook, windows-sbs-2011

I am trying to connect a desktop to exchange via Outlook Anywhere.  I have it working if I am connected over the VPN, but when I disconnect from the VPN it gives me the following error: There is a problem with the proxy server's security certificate.  The security certificate is not from a trusted certifying authority. Outlook is unable to connect to the proxy server remote.domainname.com (errror code 8).  Then a security alert box pops up saying basically the same thing.  My server is a SBS2011 and my client is Outlook 2010.  I have already gone to https://remote.domainname.com/owa and installed the security certificate in trusted root certification authorities.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Thank you
Matt Sindle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a self-installer and here are the locations.

Local Disk: c:\users\Public\Public Downloads
UNC: \servername\Public\Public Downloads
UNC: \sites\Public\Public Downloads

Comment: ...??? What's this thing?